# Как узнать доскроллился ли textview до конца android?

Tags: android, textview

У меня есть textview:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPolicy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/gray" />
```

и вот как я скрол добавил:

```
textPolicy.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

и вот собственно вопрос, как узнать что моя простыня текста проскролиллась до конца. В ios такая штука вроде есть, а в android я не нашел. Есть какой-то способ?

Comment: может ответ кроется в том, что вы хотите реализовать словив конец?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316743/detect-end-of-scrollview

Comment: @TimurVI, я хочу показать при достижении низа списка две кнопки, думал над scrollView но может есть какая-то возможность сделать это через скроллинг textView?